# Check the status of the container in Github repo

Tags: python, docker, github

I have a repo in guthub and there are shared containers(folders) in them. I need to pass the container name and check if it is running. I have a script in place as mentioned below:

```
from typing import Optional
import docker


def is_container_running(container_name: str) -> Optional[bool]:

    RUNNING = "running"
    docker_client = docker.from_env()
    try:
        container = docker_client.containers.get(container_name)
    except docker.errors.NotFound as exc:
        print(f"Check container name\n{exc.explanation}")
    else:
        container_state = container.attrs["State"]
        return container_state["Status"] == RUNNING


if __name__ == "__main__":
    container_name = "folder1"
    result = is_container_running(container_name)
    print(result)
```

This is the structure of the repo and I have created newfolder and new_script.py has the above python code.

```
my_repo
    folder1
        file1.py
        Dockerfile
    folder2
        file1.py
        Dockerfile
    folder3
        file1.py
        file2.py
        Dockerfile
    newfolder
        new_script.py
```

If I pass "folder1" in the container_name variable, Im getting this message:

`Check container name No such container: folder1 None`

How do I need to check the status of the container in my repo? Pls suggest.

Comment: Your question mentions three different concepts, a source code repository (GitHub), a filesystem directory (`./folder1`), and a Docker container.  How are you checking out the source code from GitHub, building the images from these directories, and starting the corresponding containers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A container can be run with any name.

`folder1` does not represent necessarily a container name, since we do not know what parameter was used for the `docker run -t <aName>` command.

But if it does, you could say that such an error ("No such container") means the status is "Not running".